# Blender fire simulation is jumping around randomly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, fire, cache

Right now I'm trying to create a simple flame to create a flipbook texture to use in Unity. The only problem is that when I bake my simulation it seems to bounce all over the place. I'm not sure why this is happening, I thought maybe it had to do with the fact that I was caching the simulation, but even when I turned the caching off this was still happening.
Nothing is animated in my scene either.

This is the tutorial I've been following for the fir seem, which I've followed step by step:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzATaYyCf9Q

And here is a reference for what is happening:
[image: Fire bug gif]

And here are the settings for the fire and the domain:

[image]

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I noticed that the frames this behavior was happening on were outside of the cached frame range. When I adjusted that range this issue was fixed.

So in short it seems like if the end of your timeline exceeds the amount of cached frames weird things start to happen.